# Find a specific pattern (regular expression) in a list of strings (Python)

Tags: python, regex, string, list

So I have this list of strings:

```
teststr = ['1 FirstString', '2x Sec String', '3rd String', 'x forString', '5X fifth']
```

What I need to do, is to get all the elements from this list that contain:

```
number + "x"
```

or

```
number + "X"
```

For example if I have the function

```
def SomeFunc(string):
    #do something
```

I would like to get an output like this:

```
2x Sec String
5X fifth
```

I found somewhere here in StackOverflow this function:

```
def CheckIfContainsNumber(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)
```

But this returns each string that has a number.

How can I expand the functions to get the desired output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `re.search` function along with the list comprehension.

```
>>> teststr = ['1 FirstString', '2x Sec String', '3rd String', 'x forString', '5X fifth']
>>> [i for i in teststr if re.search(r'\d+[xX]', i) ]
['2x Sec String', '5X fifth']
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits. `[xX]` matches both upper and lowercase `x`.

By defining it as  a separate function.

```
>>> def SomeFunc(s):
        return [i for i in s if re.search(r'\d+[xX]', i)]

>>> print(SomeFunc(['1 FirstString', '2x Sec String', '3rd String', 'x forString', '5X fifth']))
['2x Sec String', '5X fifth']
```